# iCal does not update Google calender

Tags: macos, ical, google-calendar

I am using iCal. I have a strange problem. If I make a task in my Google calender, iCal automatically shows that task on the calender. But, if I put a task in my iCal, Google calender does not update that task. I do not know why??

For your information I am using

Mac OSX Lion: 10.7.5
iCal: 5.0.3

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Do you choose the correct calendar, when you create the event/task?

Comment: Thanks, I did not select default calender as my Google calender, before in my iCal preference. Now It works.